# \pscirclebox misaligned

Tags: pstricks

For my example `\pscirclebox` doesn't align right and the circled object is way too high. See the MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pstricks,auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

$$a\pscirclebox{=}b$$

a\pscirclebox{=}b

\end{document}
```

Is there a cure?

Comment: It could be a good idea, if you could try your example first at yourself ...

Comment: +1 for that.  Sorry, Herbert.  Now it's a working example.  BTW, I've updated my distribution (TeXlive on macOS) today.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Hi, why you use double signs dollar instead of `\[...\]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`auto-pst-pdf` looks for an pspicture environment for the correct cropping of the created image which has *always* no depth. Use `xelatex` without `auto-pst-pdf` or tell `auto-pst-pdf` that there is some PostScript stuff:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pstricks,auto-pst-pdf}
\newcommand\kreisel[1]{\pscirclebox{#1}}
\newcommand\ps[1]{\begin{postscript}$#1$\end{postscript}}

\begin{document}
    \[
    \begin{postscript}$a\pscirclebox{=}b$\end{postscript}
    \]

    \centering
    \begin{postscript}
        a\pscirclebox{=}b   
    \end{postscript}

\ps{y=a+b\kreisel{x^2}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot.  But my goal is to circle some objects like \ln(y) in running text (for some obscure reasons), like "bla blub \kreisel{\ln(y)} blabber".  At the moment I'm using \def\kreisel#1{\raisebox{-1ex}{\pscirclebox[framesep=0pt]{#1}}}

Comment: That makes no difference. Inside the `postscript` environment you have to reactivate the math mode. thats all ...

Comment: Excuse me for my dull example.  Hasn't few to do with mathmode.  I would like to have a macro which works like \textcircled, but with the circle's size being adequate.  Always starting a postscript environment seems too annoying for me.  Just want to write \[y=a+b\kreisel{$x^2$}\].

Comment: see edieted answer